# Alteração de valor em opção do elemento select

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom

Estou tentando adicionar uma opção num select:

```
function add(){
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = "0101";
    opt.text = "foo";
}
```

Esse código funciona.

Minha dúvida é por que quando eu retiro as aspas duplas da linha onde passo o valor para a opção o valor dela passa a ser 65 ?

Comment: Sei que não responde a pergunta, mas os values dos forms são sempre strings, por isso devem ser atribuidos entre aspas mesmo.

Comment: Eu concordo com você em partes, pois se esse código fosse escrito direto html você estaria certo, mas isso está sendo feito em javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@FelippeTadeu o Javascript começa a fazer [bit manipulation](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/2550-javascript-bit-manipulation.html) quando encontra o valor `0101` (que em 8bit ascii é igual ao decimal 65);

Quando os numeros/valores que queres atribuir a uma variavel **não** são inteiros, ou decimais (`1.2`, pex), convém por esses valores entre pelicas.

> Eu concordo com você em partes, pois se esse código fosse escrito direto html você estaria certo, mas isso está sendo feito em javascript. –  Felippe Tadeu

Isto está certo até um ponto, como podes ver no teu código.